# Getting an image button drop down menu to stick when selected

Tags: jquery

I'm simply trying to get whatever button (color) I select in the drop-down menu to stick once it's clicked on. Right now whatever color I choose the menu just slides back up and defaults to the blue. Thank you for your help!

heres my query and the fiddle is below:

```
var nav = $("#catpicker");  
//add indicators and hovers to submenu parents  
nav.find("li").each(function() {  
  if ($(this).find("ul").length > 0) {    
      //show subnav on hover  
      $(this).mouseenter(function() {  
          $(this).find("ul").stop(true, true).slideDown();  
      });  
      //hide submenus on exit  
      $(this).mouseleave(function() {  
          $(this).find("ul").stop(true, true).slideUp();  
      });  
  }  
});

})(jQuery);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/davidzupec/xcCNK/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function(){

var hover =true;
var isClicked = false;

$("#menu").hover(
    function(){
        if(hover && !isClicked){
        $("#submenu").animate({height:"235px"});
        $("#submenu").on('click', 'li', function(){
            $(this).siblings('li').hide();
            $(this).addClass('clicked').siblings('li').removeClass('clicked');
            hover = false;
            isClicked = true;
            });
        }
        else {

        $(".active").show();
        $("#submenu").animate({height:"235px"});
        };

    },
        function(){
        if(isClicked){
        $("#submenu").animate({height:"55px"},500, function(){
                $(".clicked").show().siblings('li').hide();
        });

        }
        else
        {
        $("#submenu").animate({height:"55px"});
        }



        }

);

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/akman/Jy7ue/ check fiddle for some css/html changes needed

what your problem was that you needed some kind of control over the state of hover and click which can be achieved with the use of variable for each and check inside if statements if true or false... hope this helps and explains

Comment: The thing is each of the nav menu li's are images. How would that work with images?

Comment: Hi Akman, sorry but I'm a little confused on how to implement this. Does the jquery code above fit into what I already have in my fiddle?

Comment: i will post the solution in fiddle but will do it tomorrow, if you dont find another solution till then... no time at the moment

Comment: Hello, sorry but this wasn't what I was looking for. I'm looking for something like this here except without the duplication of icons: http://jsbin.com/omuvaq/1/edit

Comment: i think its exactly what you want :)

Comment: Hey akman it looks great but I lost my slow slide up and slide down speed. Is there a way to get that back?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/akman/Jy7ue/ check it now... minor css and html changes changes

Comment: Looks great! Thank you for all your effort in this. Occasionally I need query/javascript developers let me know if your interested.

Comment: sure why not :) glad i could help you

Comment: Hi Akman, I have a quick question. I noticed that on the ipad when I touch the "ALL" button it doesn't drop down. Do you know of any issues within the script that would cause that to not work on iPads? Thank You!

Comment: do you use Modernizr if not try to add it to your page http://modernizr.com/ and tell me if the problem is fixed. if not i will re-code the script so it can use the touchstart and touchend method instead of hover .. when it's an apple tablet

Comment: Hey akman, yeah I have modernizr loaded up, which is why I'm surprised that it doesn't work on the iPad. Do you think using that touchstart and touchend method would work for the iPad?

Comment: well what has to be done is first detect pc or tablet which can be done with something like that `if((navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry)/i)) )){//tablet version here}else{//pc version here}` then should add jQuery mobile and use .tap() method for tablet version...this should work... i will recode the whole js example to fit your needs when i get some spare time during weekend

Comment: akman.me/davidz i uploaded to my server so you can take the code just view source

Comment: Hey akman, great thank you! I can't seem to get to it though, I think your server might be down because the page isn't loading.

Comment: Hey akman, unfortunately still no luck. I keep getting a failed to open page.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/akman/tfv4X/ here but you cant emulate tablets on jsfiddle or at least i dont know how... and remember you need to add  http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js in order for the code to work

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/xcCNK/5/)?

```
$(document).ready(function($){  
var nav = $("#catpicker"), bool = true, bool2 = true;  
nav.find("li").each(function() {  
  if ($(this).find("ul").length > 0) {     
      $(this).mouseenter(function() {  
          if(bool2)
          {
              $(this).find("ul").stop(true, true).slideDown();  
              bool = false;
          }
      });  
      $("img").click(function() {
           bool = true;
           bool2 = false;
           $(this).find("ul").stop(true, true);
       }); 
      $(this).mouseleave(function() {  
          if(bool == false)
          {
              $(this).find("ul").stop(true, true).slideUp();  
          }
      });  
  }  
});

})(jQuery);
```

**EDIT** Now that I understand what you mean, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/xcCNK/12/) is what you want, I changed the html some so suit it

```
$(document).ready(function($){  
  var nav = $("#catpicker"), bool = true, bool2 = true;  
  $("li").click(function() {
      $(".first").removeClass("first");
      $(this).addClass("first");
      var current = $(this);
      current.prev().prev().before(current);
      current.prev().before(current);
  });

  if (nav.find("ul").length > 0) {     
      $(this).mouseenter(function() {  
          $("ul li").css("visibility", "visible");
      });  

  $(this).mouseleave(function() {  
      $(this).find("ul li").not(".first").stop(true, true).slideUp().css("visibility", "hidden").slideDown();  
  });  
  }  

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Hello and thank you but for some reason it's not working. for example: lets say I click on the yellow box in the dropdown menu. What I simply want is for the yellow button to then replace the default blue. Basically just showing that's the one I click on.

Answer (score 0):

I hope, that I understanded the question correct.
This code will select a square as shown und than slides the menu up:

```
$(document).ready(function($){  
    // initial: the first item from the list
    $('#static').html($('#allcat').html());
    $('#static').css("background-color",$('#allcat').parent().css("background-color"));
    // replace static item with clicked
    $('#items li').click(function(){
        $('#static').html($(this).html());
        $('#static').css("background-color",$(this).css("background-color"));
    });
    // mouse events
    $('#container').mouseenter(function(){
        $('#items').slideDown();
    });
    $('#items').mouseleave(function(){
        $('#items').slideUp();
    });

})(jQuery);
```

I've changed the html structure. look here:
http://jsfiddle.net/xcCNK/9/

Comment: Sorry gentlemen thanks for the effort but unfortunatley thats not quite what i was looking for. this is just supposed to work like your typical menu drop down navigation. whatever link you click is the one that'll be selected.

Comment: sorry, i don't get the point. please provide pictures of the starting state, which event you do and what you expect what will happen

Comment: heres what im working on. I just want the button to be highlighted on whatever one you select: see the "all" button http://fireflyliving.com/new/

Comment: please decide...you wrote first that you want it to be highlighted und edited your question to "stick" and now your writing about highlighting again. you're confusing me

Comment: If you see on the web link above I just want it to stay or stick, whatever you call it, on the button you click on in the drop down menu.

Comment: Let' see if I got it: You want a menu, wich slides out, when you hover over it. If you click on e.g. "Pending" you want that the menu slides up to so that only "pending" and "sold" are visibile. or  do you want that only "pending" is visible under the "all" button?

Comment: hello, I just simply wanted whatever button I click on will be visible, i.e. pending. Right know the way it works is whatever button I click on the nav slides up to "all".

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the HTML a bit (images couldn't be loaded), but that has nothing to do with the jQuery code: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gH7fm/2/)

The click on the underlying `li` elements makes the clicked `li` swap places with the first (toplevel) one

```
first.find("li").click(function () {
    var ul = first.children("ul");
    var clicked = $(this);
    ul.remove();
    first.after(clicked);
    clicked.append(ul);
    ul.append(first);
    clicked.mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).find("ul").stop(true, true).slideUp();
    });
    clicked.mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).find("ul").stop(true, true).slideDown();
    });
    clicked.click(function () {
        // TODO: Reassign click to new toplevel item
    });
});
```

The only thing that needs to be done is to reassign the click event to the new toplevel `li`